# Dxtory recording randomly crashing game

Tags: video, codec, software, video-recording

Whenever I try to record gameplay with Dxtory (using the h.264 codec) my game will crash after a seemingly random amount of time, although it is usually after at least 30 minutes. Dxtory produces no error logs and there is no recording because I have to end the game's process to close it and this seems to make Dxtory just toss out the entire file... The game in question is Counter Strike: Global Offensive, but I don't know if that makes a difference. I am not sure if the codec is the source of the problem, but I was wondering if someone with a little more knowledge than me has any idea of what is wrong. These are my video settings:
[image][image]

I have done 2 successful recordings with Dxtory so far, but I cannot remember if they were both using the default codec or if the second one was using H.264. Is this the fault of my settings or is it the codec that is malfunctioning?

Comment: Does it work if you stop prior to the crash?  Are you able to monitor your system performance (memory and CPU usage) leading up to the crash?

Comment: No, I cannot really monitor it because I don't know when it'll happen. BUT, after you asked, I tried just starting a recording and stopping it, and Dxtory gets stuck on FIN (right before the recording ends, but the FPS counter is still the recording color) and the game crashes... I'll be using the default codec until I know how to fix this.